# Challenge friends in online games with out Facebook sign in

Tags: community, user-communication

I'm currently working on a project, an SAT online game, and I'm stuck because I can't find clear way to show the user that we can challenge friends that aren't yet sign in the game, by sending them a record of the game.

Can anyone suggest a way that allow users to send a challenge to a friend not signed in yet in the game? (We can't use Facebook to sign in because of schools policy).

Comment: I guess the assumption is that the user won't know their friend's email address?

Comment: Email address would be ideal, if not maybe you could send an SMS with a link

Comment: Thaks MAtt and Anindya!After testing I believe that the problem is getting the user to know that the challenge is going to be recorded and sent to the friend...people think they are playing alone and also they never choose the option "challenge a friend" because they think they don't have friends in the game already..

Comment: Sounds like you might need to change the "challenge a friend" text to something else that makes it clear that a 'friend' is not necessarily someone that is signed in. How is the record sent to the friend?

Comment: Maybe "invite a friend"  or something  along the lines would make it clearer? Some  apps on my mobile (and I think LinkedIn) use that phrasing

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the challenge correctly, its something that can be referenced by link.

If that is the case, then perhaps give instructions under the caption "Challenge a friend!" and under it "Send this link to a friend to challenge them in this SAT Battle Royal or whatever!" With a textbox with a **short** link for them to copy with a button nearby that will copy the link to the clipboard (nice for phone users).

Then students will have the option to send it via email or text message or facebook or whatever means they prefer.

I think that would be received better, since logging into email takes effort, text message is a pretty effortless way to communicate, and people tend to be reluctant to enter email addresses into form fields, especially emails that aren't their own.